# applying Xpaths to PHP::Libxml - How to do that?

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dom, xpath

i want to parse a site with the  PHP DOM-Document way: Note it is faster and easier to use. Some of you have convinced me!! One question - since i am a php-newbie ;-)  can i apply the XPaths-code

Example: http://buergerstiftungen.de/cps/rde/xchg/SID-F8780E81-ABF20567/buergerstiftungen/hs.xsl/db.htm

Goal: to fetch the results ( approx 213 different records) too and parse them in order to get a database-dump for the saving on a local MySQL-Db!?

by the way: see two resultpages:

http://buergerstiftungen.de/cps/rde/xchg/SID-F8780E81-ABF20567/buergerstiftungen/hs.xsl/db_20302.htm
http://buergerstiftungen.de/cps/rde/xchg/SID-F8780E81-ABF20567/buergerstiftungen/hs.xsl/db_20289.htm

You see there are lots of information stored...

well i have tried to do write a scraper with Perl - but i had no luck. Perl is for newbies very very hard.  Afterwards i tired to write a parser in PHP - it is a bit easier. But  the site (see the detail-resultpages) are a bit complex. How to parse them - in order to get the dataset for a locally based MySQL database.  Then i have more opportunities for a retrieval.
I want to get the datas to have them local (on my OpenSuse Linux System Version 11.3) in a MySQL-database.

well: i have three parts:

1. fetching
2. parsing
3. storing (in MySQL: that is creating a MySQL-dump)

Since i have some very little experience with XPath  i have a Xpather-Tool in my Mozilla-Browser. But i am not sure how i should apply them - see the data i gathered - below: 
Perhaps some of you can help me here - and show me how to apply them in a parsercode:

I love to hear from you

See here some details: 
for the results (from the approx 213 different records) - see two resultpages: - gathered some Xpath-datas:

**Example: Bürgerstiftung Wiesloch**
http://buergerstiftungen.de/cps/rde/xchg/SID-A7DCD0D1-702CE0FA/buergerstiftungen/hs.xsl/db_20289.htm

/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='marginalblock']/div[1]/p

**1. Gründungsgeschichte**
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[1]/strong

**2. Kurzvorstellung/Ziele**
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[2]/span[2]/span/b

**3. Projekte**
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[3]/span[2]/span/strong

**Kontakt:** 
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='marginalblock']/div[1]/h6

Question: well, how to apply the gained datas in the Libxml - in order to get the PARSER-Part up and running!? I am a XPath-starter!

Look forward to hear from you!
zero

PS - if i have to add more infos - or if i have to ask more propperly - plz let me know! Sorry for being the newbie!;-)

PPS - and update: i have the Mysql-part: it can look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(30) default NULL,
`contact-details` varchar(30) default NULL,
`street` varchar(30) default NULL,
`postal-code` varchar(30) default NULL,
`town` varchar(30) default NULL,
`phone` varchar(30) default NULL,
`email` varchar(30) default NULL,
`homepage` varchar(30) default NULL,
`summary` varchar(30) default NULL,
`projects` varchar(30) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

something like this would fit the needs..

**Update;** many many thanks Lenzai for the quick answer:

you suggest to try something like this:

```
$url="http://...";
$xpath_query="/html/body/...";

/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='marginalblock']/div[1]/p
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[1]/strong
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[2]/span[2]/span/b
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='contentblock']/div/p[3]/span[2]/span/strong
/html/body/div[@id='main']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='inner']/div[@id='marginalblock']/div[1]/h6

$ch=curl_init($url);
$res=curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument()
$dom->loadHTML($res);
$xpath=new DomXPath($dom);
$node= $xpath->query($xpath_query)->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

I have Curl enabled here. That is no problem. And the Xpaths i should enter

in this line:   $xpath_query="/html/body/...";

**Question:** should i enter all Xpaths that are mentioned above..**from 1. to 3... and so forth** How does this look like finally Can you help me here - i am very very new to php?

Look  forward  to hear from you!! Many many thanks for all and any help!

zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$url="http://...";
$xpath_query="/html/body/...";
$ch=curl_init($url);
$res=curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument()
$dom->loadHTML($res);
$xpath=new DomXPath($dom);
$node= $xpath->query($xpath_query)->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue;
```

you just need to enable curl in your php.ini

Comment: Hello Lenzai, I have Curl enabled here. That is no problem. And the Xpaths i should enter in this line:   $xpath_query="/html/body/..."; 

**Question:** should i enter all Xpaths that are mentioned above..**from 1. to 3... and so forth** How does this look like finally Can you help me here - i am very very new to php?

Look  forward  to hear from you!! Many many thanks for all and any help!

Comment: loop over the last two lines for each xpath_query.
to clean up code, you should extract two functions: 1 to get xpath from url, 1 to apply query to xpath object.